# Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I am tryiing to make next js 13 mdx blog website with the latest app router
I am getting this error => Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'
In next js 12 and pages directory its working but in the latest app router it's not working

this is my code,

```
"use client"

import Head from 'next/head';
import BlogSidebar from '../../components/blog/sidebar';
import Pagination from '../../components/blog/pagination';
import fs from 'fs';
import matter from 'gray-matter';
import { join } from 'path';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'


export async function getStaticProps() {
  const blogsDirectory = join(process.cwd(), '_blog');
  const files = fs.readdirSync(blogsDirectory);

  let posts = files.map((fileName) => {
    const slug = fileName.replace(/\.md$/, '');
    const fullPath = join(blogsDirectory, `${slug}.md`);
    const readFile = fs.readFileSync(fullPath, 'utf8');
    const { data: frontmatter } = matter(readFile);
    return {
      slug,
      frontmatter,
      
    };
  });

  posts = posts.sort((job1, job2) => (job1.frontmatter.date > job2.frontmatter.date ? -1 : 1));

  return {
    props: {
      posts,
    },
    
  };
}


const page = ({ posts }) => {

  console.log(posts, "posts");
```

[image]

Comment: This may also help https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/module-not-found-cant-resolve-fs

Comment: I think you can't use fs anywhere anymore except possibly api routes, but I'm not sure if there's a clear explanation why in any of the above answers

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues in the code snippet you posted.

1. `getStaticProps` is not supported in Next.js 13 app router. You are going to get the following error if you try to use it in a page under the `app` directory:

> "getStaticProps" is not supported in app/.  Read more:
> https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching

You should read the above mentioned docs on data fetching in Next.js 13 app router.

2. You declared your page as a client component, but expect it to access the server-side file system. This is just not going to work this way.

You are going to need to rewrite your code to make it compatible with the `app` dir. Here is how you can approach this problem:

```
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";

async function getPosts() {
  const files = fs.readdirSync(path.resolve("_blog"));

  // read posts

  return posts;
}

export default async function Home() {
  const posts = await getPosts();

  console.log(posts);

  // render posts
}
```

The following migration guide is also going to be helpful.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration

Comment: why would this work if you do no separate files?

Comment: Because it's a server component.

Answer (score 0):

The fs module is not available in the client-side. You can use the next/dynamic component to load the file contents on the server-side and then render them on the client-side.

Here is the updated code:

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import BlogSidebar from '../../components/blog/sidebar';
import Pagination from '../../components/blog/pagination';
import matter from 'gray-matter';
import { join } from 'path';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const blogsDirectory = join(process.cwd(), '_blog');
  const files = fs.readdirSync(blogsDirectory);

  let posts = files.map((fileName) => {
    const slug = fileName.replace(/\.md$/, '');
    const fullPath = join(blogsDirectory, `${slug}.md`);
    const readFile = fs.readFileSync(fullPath, 'utf8');
    const { data: frontmatter } = matter(readFile);
    return {
      slug,
      frontmatter,
    };
  });

  posts = posts.sort((job1, job2) => (job1.frontmatter.date > job2.frontmatter.date ? -1 : 1));

  return {
    props: {
      posts,
    },
  };
}

const page = ({ posts }) => {
  const dynamicPost = useRouter().query.post;
  const post = posts.find(post => post.slug === dynamicPost);

  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>My Blog</title>
      </Head>
      <BlogSidebar />
      <main>
        {post && (
          <article>
            <h1>{post.frontmatter.title}</h1>
            <p>{post.frontmatter.content}</p>
          </article>
        )}
      </main>
      <Pagination />
    </div>
  );
};

export default page;
```

This code will first load the list of posts on the server-side. Then, it will render the post that is specified in the query string. If there is no post specified in the query string, it will render the first post in the list.

Comment: The OP was trying to run this code under the app directory, so the getStaticProps won’t cut it.